# How can I make two different UI forms work under the same MainWindow in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, tabs

I am trying to make different toolbars have different UIs. I am not able to work them under same main window that when I close the main window all of those get closed and also they all remain linked to each other and the main window.

```
/* I am trying to made the different toolbar having different ui now I am not able to 

work them  under same main window that when
I close the main window all of those get closed and also they all remain linked to each other and the main window.
*/

// mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "code_dockwidget.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMdiSubWindow>
#include <cmath>
#include <QTime>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
      ui->setupUi(this);
      setWindowTitle(tr("GD CAD"));
      ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->resize(600,500);
    ui->actionLine->connect(ui->actionLine,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(drawLine()));
}
void MainWindow::drawLine(){
    scene->addLine(100,100,20,200);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


//code_dockwidget.cpp

#include "code_dockwidget.h"
#include "ui_code_dockwidget.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QFileDialog>

Code_DockWidget::Code_DockWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Code_DockWidget)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);


}

Code_DockWidget::~Code_DockWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Code_DockWidget::on_Save_code_clicked()
{
    QFile sFile(mFilename);
            if(sFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
            {
                QTextStream out(&sFile);

                out<<ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

                sFile.flush();
                sFile.close();
            }

}

void Code_DockWidget::on_Load_code_clicked()
{
    QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open a File ");
       if ( !file.isEmpty())
       {
           QFile sFile(file);
           if(sFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text ))
           {
               QTextStream in(&sFile);
               QString text =in.readAll();
               sFile.close();

               ui->textEdit->setPlainText(text);
           }
       }
}

void Code_DockWidget::on_SaveAs_code_clicked()
{
    QString file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Open a File");

            if(!file.isEmpty())
            {
                mFilename=file;
                Code_DockWidget::on_Load_code_clicked();
            }
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's possible but, I think it's a bit tricky and not a nice idea. If you want to switch between two different toolbars, just create your own toolbar (two classes which inherit QToolbar), and set your toolbar1 or toolbar2 when you want in your mainwindow.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. What is closed when you close main window? What is linked to what? What does it all have to do with toolbars? You also have an obvious error by calling `ui->setupUi(this);` twice.

Comment: I mean when I close the mainwindow I want that all other toolbar associated to it must be closed. I want to work it like as somehow in photoshop like software where we can drag drop etc. Please suggest me some way that will be most suitable initially I want to work on different ui and then merge them all.